# How can i have network access to linux server from a computer that shares internet connection?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have a spare router and a second pc running linux server. My main pc runs windows 10.
My initial problem was to have ssh access to linux server via windows 10. I solved
by creating a second network between those using my spare router.
Although i wanded internet access to linux server so as windows pc has wifi internet access i shared the connection from ethernet connection providing internet to router and to linux server as a result.
Although i lost my direct ssh connection to linux from windows pc. How i can have
both internet and direct network ssh access to linux server based on this setup?

Comment: This question is very unclear, and all over the place.  Why do you need a second router and not just a switch or access point? What is the configuration of the routers and what IP ranges are in use?

Answer (score 1):

> I solved by creating a second network between those using my spare
> router. ....    i lost my direct ssh connection to linux from windows
> pc. How i can have both internet and direct network ssh access to
> linux server based on this setup?

Adding the second router has you did has very likely given you two networks (two subnets).

Put the second network on the same subnet as the first network.

This will give you (as you asked) direct connection between computers and Internet on both.

To put two routers on the same subnet, follow the general steps below (has worked for me for a long time and numerous routers).

Make sure you can access the router settings on both routers - you will need this.

Connect a LAN port on the second router to a LAN port on the first router. Do not connect to the WAN port of the second router.

Give the second router a Static IP address on the main network. This avoids the second router getting lost if you reset things.

Turn DHCP OFF on the second router.

Now you have one subnet and you can make everything work together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what i want to know is if it possible using the windows pc to share the internet connection of windows pc to the second router that linux server is connected via ethernet and have ssh access at the same time FROM windows pc to linux server.  I am obligated to use this setup due to long distance of the main router and avoid spreading pc all over the house.

Comment: You connect both machines to a router (either router as I suggested above) and then both have Internet and can share direct connection for sharing files or whatever. With two routers there is no need to share the Internet connection of a PC. Do that from the router (either one).